# Blockchain Payment receive api

Tags: php, blockchain

While using blockchain receive payment api, what if some one send less then require fund or some one send extra fund on same one time generated address.

does fund will automatically refund to sender or not ?

what to do if i want to refund that amount back to user who send less fund or double fund on that address?

any one have information regarding this?

Comment: By 'blockchain' do you mean cryptocurrencies in general, or a specifc implementation e.g. Bitcoin? As this may well be implementation-specific. You might do better asking on the [Bitcoin StackExchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Well i am just asking for bitcoin payments, which made through blockchain payment api v2